# Postgresql: how to revoke grant option from role?

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-revoke

I have postgresql 15 db.
There I have different roles based on which users are created.

What I need is to revoke grant option for roles. In my company we need to do it via different system.

I tried:

```
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL ON SCHEMA schema_name FROM role_name;
```

but it does not work.

What do I need to do to revoke grant option from roles?

Comment: GRANT/REVOKE are commands not db objects and thus not themselves subject to grant/revoke privileges. The ability to issue these commands stems from object ownership: if you own an object you can grant/revoke access and **this cannot be taken away.** A possible option is to create a `OwnsEverything` role which - well owns everything - all tables, all views, all roles, etc. You do not grant this role to any other role/user, use it for your *different system*.  Note that a `superuser` can still issue grant/revoke. **You essentially control this through administration procedures.**

Comment: Slight correction. Roles are not owned so above should not include *all roles*.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you have sufficient privileges (most preferably superuser) to run the REVOKE command then try `REVOKE <the_privilege or ALL> ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema_name> FROM <role_name> CASCADE;`

You can also consult the [Postgres docs on REVOKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) to get more information on the REVOKE command.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Besides that, you should hardly ever use a superuser role while working with the database cluster. On AWS and Azure you don't even get a superuser role